Mapping Doctrine of superclass Entity inside a bundle doesn't work
i got a problem on my symfony project with zenstruck/messenger-monitor-bundle
When i do the command bin/console doctrine:mapping:info i see
bin/console doctrine:mapping:info
 Found 10 mapped entities:

 [OK]   App\Entity\AnonHistory
 [OK]   App\Entity\RequestHistory
 [OK]   App\Entity\SyncTrack
 [OK]   App\Entity\AnonHistoryAnonymizerStatus
 [OK]   App\Entity\Customer
 [OK]   App\Entity\ProcessedMessage
 [OK]   App\Entity\Activity
 [OK]   App\Entity\SyncType
 [OK]   App\Entity\ActivityType
 [OK]   Zenstruck\Messenger\Monitor\History\Model\ProcessedMessage

This is my entity file
<?php

// src/Entity/ProcessedMessage.php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zenstruck\Messenger\Monitor\History\Model\ProcessedMessage as BaseProcessedMessage;

#[ORM\Entity(readOnly: true)]
#[ORM\Table('processed_messages')]
class ProcessedMessage extends BaseProcessedMessage
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    public function id(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

but when i generate migration i got :
$this->addSql('CREATE SEQUENCE processed_messages_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE processed_messages (id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');

The superclass's fields definied in the bundle doesnt appear when i make a doctrine:migrations:diff
this is my config doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_SERVER_VERSION)%'
                host: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_HOST)%'
                port: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_PORT)%'
                dbname: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_NAME)%'
                user: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_USER)%'
                password: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_PWD)%'
                charset: UTF8
                schema_filter: ~^(?!cache_items)$~
            db_migration:
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_SERVER_VERSION)%'
                host: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_HOST)%'
                port: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_PORT)%'
                dbname: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_NAME)%'
                user: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_USER_MIGRATE)%'
                password: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_PWD_MIGRATE)%'
                charset: UTF8
                schema_filter: ~^(?!cache_items)$~
            test:
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_SERVER_VERSION)%'
                host: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_HOST)%'
                port: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_PORT)%'
                dbname: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_NAME)%'
                user: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_USER_MIGRATE)%'
                password: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_PWD_MIGRATE)%'
                charset: UTF8
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    ZenstruckMessengerMonitor:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: xml
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/zenstruck/messenger-monitor-bundle/src/Resources/config/doctrine'
                        prefix: 'Zenstruck\Messenger\Monitor\History\Model'
                        alias: ZenstruckMessengerMonitor
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: attribute
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            
            db_migration:
                connection: db_migration
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Mig:
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Mig
when@test:
    doctrine:
      dbal:
        connections:
          default:
            dbname: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_NAME)%_test'

          db_migration:
            dbname: '%env(MAWS_PR0JECT_DB_NAME)%_test'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system

Configuring zenstruck/messenger-monitor-bundle
